# Need help perfoming SQL Insert using parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Articles_InsertArticle

    @Article nvarchar(MAX),
    @UsersID uniqueidentifier
AS
    INSERT INTO Articles 
          (UsersID,Article,PageNumber)
    SELECT @UsersID,
           @Article,
           floor(COUNT(ArticleID)/5)
      FROM Articles
```

I am not sure if the syntax correct..But what I want is to pass the query 2 parameters: Article and UserID..insert both, then insert the page number..Basically get the count of the article ID and divide by 5... I cant get an awkward number. I also want the Number to be a whole number.. (so not 1/5 but 0..not 9/5 , but 1)

UPDATED ABOVE..

It tells me to declare UsersID..syntax error

Comment: When you count articleid from Articles you will simply get the count of all records in Articles, not for any particular article. I can't imagine this is what you want.

Comment: Should probably remove the ASP.NET tag, as this seems to have nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Articles (UsersID,Article,PageNumber) 
VALUES (@UsersID, @Article, ROUND(SELECT COUNT(ArticleID)/5 FROM Articles),0)
```

Comment: it says that i must declare the scaler userid...but it is declared..hmm

Comment: Note that this will get the count of the articles prior to the insertion of the new record -- if that's intended or not.  If you want the post count, you'll need to add one to the `COUNT`.

Comment: Why does it tell me that the UsersID is undeclared?

Comment: still tells me that UsersID needs to be declared

Comment: I was missing a comma between the variables..corrected it now

Comment: If count is 50.. then 50/5.. the page number is 10..thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following where PageNumber comes from. But at the very least, the structure of your insert statement is incorrect and should look like this:

```
insert into Articles(UsersID, Article, PageNumber)
select @UsersID, @Article, count(*) / 5
FROM Articles
WHERE Article = @Article
```

I took a guess at what you're looking for with the PageNumber, but we'll likely need more information.

Comment: floor(count(*)/5) will ensure that PageNumber will be an int (though depending on the platform, it might return an int anyway)

Comment: it is a page number..what more information you need. it is a field.. i think under your count..i am very likely to get an exception...cause a double will result

Comment: for almost all platforms i can think of, count() returns an int, and 5 is an int, and an int divided by an int is an int. as for pagenumber, is it supposed to be a count of all pagenumbers in the entire table? just a count for those matching a certain criteria?

Comment: lol..derek..why to use a where clause..i think you lost me a bit

Comment: i don't know why you're choosing to laugh at someone that is trying to help you solve a poorly described problem

Comment: Everyone seemed to understand the problem but you..I wanted to divide the count of the ArticleID and then to divide it by 5..while avoiding doubles...thats all i asked

Comment: but that doesn't seem to make sense Matrix.  A table named Articles would lead me to assume that you have multiple articles in the table. So counting the number of records in the Articles table and dividing by 5 (which is what you're asking for), would seem to produce some random integer with no relationship to the either the user or the article you're inserting.  We're saying you need to check your logic.